# How to add a Header & Footer in TinyMCE editor?

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to add a Header & Footer in TinyMCE editor, so the user could get a predefined "Blank" page to edit and have default Header & Footer. User only needs to input the customized content.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to add the header and footer to the content when the editor initialzes. But keep in mind that you will have to remove it before saving if you do not want to have them stored in the db. Here is the init code to make it work. You will need to make use of the [setup parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onInit)

```
// Adds an observer to the onInit event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
         var header = "<header>ABCD</header>",
             footer = "<div>footer</div>",
             content = ed.getContent();

         content = header + content + footer;
         ed.setContent(content);
      });
   }
});
```

Additionally you will need to define your added tags as *valid elements* in the tinymce configuration. Have a look at the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) setting for this (maybe you can use the *extended_valid_elements* setting).

Comment: that might work. my question is, I have a textarea to edit and preview the file with header & footer, this is kind of a email template editor, so after edit from this textarea, user should be able to use this email template to send out email with header footer and content, so I think I do need to save into database and not just add everytime I init tinymce.....right?

Comment: that would be the better way in this case

Comment: Then I need to integrate with legacy database which don't have header & footer for the content now, and anticipate new email template with default footer & header build in....

Comment: When printing, and there is more than one page, the footer in only in the last page and the header in the first page.